# Wake up Arduino in sleep mode after x hours

Tags: arduino

I need to put an Arduino to sleep mode to save battery, but after x hour (A choice that makes the user), I need that the Arduino wakes up, do some action, and then goes to sleep again. How can I do it? I see that the sleep mode can be interrupt by Interrupt, but I need that the interrupt is trigger not by a pin but by the time. Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no apparent programming question here. Questions like this can be asked on [Arduino.SE](//arduino.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question depends on how much low power you need and which time precision you need. Achive 200nA sleep current requires some work and time precision is a compromise with low power.

However, here are some clues:

- Use an external RTC module able to generate an interrupt at some precise moment
- Use an external 32kHz Xtal to clock timer2 asynchronously and generate interupt to wake up from "power-save" sleep mode
- Use the internal watchdog timer in interrupt and reset mode to wake up from "power-down" mode. You will wake up every 8s but for very short duration if the code is optimized.

The last solution seems most appropriate for some basic demo. With a good code you will achieve honorable results. And do not forget to read "Minimizing Power Consumption" section of the MCU datasheet.

**EDIT**

> how much more current I consume if the Arduino wakes up every 8 seconds? 
>   There is a way to calculate it?

Too calculate the average current (I would say estimate) read datasheet at section "atmega328P typical characteristics"

- @5V 8MHz the consumption is about 5.5mA,
- in power down @5V with watchdog 6.5µA.

With about 1ms active every 8s you will achieve 7.2µA mean.

Note that the board consumption is not only the MCU on Arduino board. With an Arduino I don't know how much you will globally consume but it will be more than my calculation. To achieve 200nA stated in datasheet, you will need to do your own board and use external low power watchdog...

> And second: the AtMega will ruin faster if wakes up every 8 seconds?

An AtMega does not have ageing issues. It can run constantly for 20 years without issues (except if you use EEPROM or flash self-programming).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The last solution is great for me, but I have some doubts: how much more current I consume if the Arduino wakes up every 8 seconds? There is a way to calculate it? And second: the AtMega will ruin faster if wakes up every 8 seconds? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know that an Arduino has many components that drain current, so I make my "Arduino on breadboard" and I achieve this results: 6.90mA with a blank sketch and  4.3μA in power down with watchdog (in average, **at 3.3V**). So my last question is, how can I estimate the consumption (like yours 7.2µA)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Eternyt You will need to know the active time (startup of RC oscillator +  ISR execution). Best way to do is add a resistor (about 100R) in serie with power supply and measure voltage accros it with an oscilloscope. The duration of the pulse is the active time, the hight is image of the active current. Then Imean=(Iactive*Tactive+Isleep*Tsleep)/(Tsleep+Tactive). Without an oscilloscope it will be difficult to estimate the active time (but you could ask if someone has an idea on electronic stackexchange).

Comment: Only one more think: I don't understand what is IactiveTactive and IsleepTsleep for. Tsleep and Tactive I imagine that are Time in sleep mode and Time in active mode. Thanks!

Comment: @Eternyt  The letter I is usually used for current (in Amps) as U or V are usually used for volatge and P for Power (in Watts) ...

Comment: Many thanks for your patience!!
So, if I put a code like this 
`void sleepTenMinutes()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 75; i++) { 
     LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF); 
  }
}`
the code can work or I have a very high error (for example if I increase the counter for reach the 10 hours, I have an error less that 30 minutes?)

Comment: @Eternyt Not sure I clearly understood the question. `i` is declared `int` thus you can count until 32765. You will get a "bug" in the for loop only for duration more than 3 day (roughly 32765*8s=72h).

Comment: No, my problem is another: I discover that the watchdog used by the library is very unprecise, and my question is how much time of error I can accumulate in 10/12 hours

Comment: @Eternyt Have a look at "typical charecteristics" in the datasheet, you will get an idea of watchdog precision. You may calibrate it using OSCCAL register (but that will de-calibrate the 8MHz internal oscillator) or compensate by SW. Low power VS precision is not easy. To answer your question, you may get up to 10% error (1h for 10 elapsed h). Here is an example more dedicated to precision than low power http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148633/how-to-make-arduino-perform-a-task-daily-at-the-required-time/39160444#39160444